# Python Selenium - Write data table in excel file

Tags: python, excel, selenium, datatable

I need to write a data table in excel file. This data table has 7 rows and 1 column, and all the values are different. My problem is only last row is written in excel file.

What I need in excel:

```
FT 202003/69362
FT 202003/62581
FT 202003/41307
FT 202003/32316
FT 202003/4664
FT 201903/215090
FT 201903/197043
```

What is happening in excel:

```
FT 201903/197043
FT 201903/197043
FT 201903/197043
FT 201903/197043
FT 201903/197043
FT 201903/197043
FT 201903/197043
```

My code:

```
faturas = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='text-description-small']//b[contains(text(),'FT')]")
    totalfaturas = len(faturas)
    for i in range(totalfaturas):
        fat = faturas[i].text
        print(fat)

    from openpyxl import *

    nf = load_workbook("C:\WebDrivers\Fatturas.xlsx")
    nf1 = nf.active
    for n in range(1, totalfaturas+1):
            nf1.cell(row=n,column=1).value=fat
            nf.save("C:\WebDrivers\Fatturas.xlsx")
```

I can print the right data table in python, but I can't write this data table in excel. Can you please help me?

Comment: `nf1.cell(row=n,column=1).value=fat`   =>   this is wrong . why using `fat` here ? just do same as you did in above loop , dynamically :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you be specific? I didn't undestand how should I use that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
for i in range(totalfaturas):
    fat = faturas[i].text
    print(fat)
```

to:

```
fat_list=[]
for fat in faturas:
    fat_list.append(fat.text)
    #print(fat.text)
```

Then, change this:

```
for n in range(1, totalfaturas+1):
        nf1.cell(row=n,column=1).value=fat
        nf.save("C:\WebDrivers\Fatturas.xlsx")
```

to:

```
for item in fat_list:
    nf1.cell(row=fat_list.index(item)+1,column=1).value=item
    nf.save("C:\WebDrivers\Fatturas.xlsx")
```